# How to use Console.ReadLine() in a project using MonoDevelop under Linux

Tags: c#, monodevelop, opensuse

I have the following sample project and I use MonoDevelop in OpenSuse.
I can build the project, but when I execute it, it does not show any console where I can enter the string. I am aware about people indicating that we should set the Project options to "Run on External Console". That option is enabled, but there is no console appearing when I execute the program under MonoDevelop. Do we have to open a console separately and attach to process, or is there another trick?

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleReadLine
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine ();
            Console.WriteLine (s);
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that feature (`Run on External Console`) was broken in some recent version(s) of MonoDevelop (and thus Visual Studio for Mac where I first encountered it). What version are you running?

Comment: === MonoDevelop ===
Version 5.9.6
Installation UUID: 250a94e4-84df-4dde-9b60-d7604834eeba
Runtime:
 Mono 5.8.0.108 (tarball Fri Jan 19 21:02:58 UTC 2018) (64-bit)
 GTK+ 2.24.31 (Breeze theme)

=== Build Information ===
Build information unavailable

=== Operating System ===
Linux
Linux linux-21ul 4.4.104-39-default #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 08:11:03 UTC 2018 (7db1912) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I am using an older version (4.0.12).  I just created a new solution and ran your code.  It opened a new terminal for the console I/O.  If nothing else, you can run your program from a separate terminal just by typing `./bin/Debug/readline.exe` (or something like that).

Comment: Mono shows me an option to run it with a different version from 5.9.6 (use 5.8.0.108) and when I run it through that, it also fails to show a console. I just installed Mono for the first time today. If I run the program through a separate terminal, I lose the possibility to debug a more complex program by running it line by line

Comment: @Nick_F The runtime is not the problem (as far as I'm aware of). That is an "older" version of MonoDevelop, give the latest stable release (`7.3.2.12`) a try.

Comment: I installed the software flatpak (recommended for installing monodevelop). I downloaded the latest monodevelop using flatpak. When I start the software, it still shows v5.9.6 and the terminal still does not appear.

Comment: I used flatpak to uninstall the previous installation of monodevelop, then I installed it again with the command "flatpack install --user --from https://download.mono-project.com/repo/monodevelop.flatpakref" and now I have MonoDevelop v7.3.3 (build 5) and I can execute the code (the terminal pops up and I can enter a string).

Answer (score 1):

Currently (Version 7.8.4 (build 2)), this is still an issue on Linux.

To address it, you need to:

1. Right-click on the **solution** (and not the *project*), and select "Options"
   [image]
2. In "Run", select "Default" under "Configurations", tick "Run on external console"
   [image]
3. Click "OK", and that's it!

I don't know if there is any way to change this behavior system-wide (that is, for all solutions), but would be interested in knowing.